# Java Regex include all letters of the alphabet except certain letters

Tags: java, regex

What I need to do is to determine whether a word consists of letters except certain letters. For example I need to test whether a word consists of the letters from the English alphabet except letters: I, V and X.

Currently I have this long regex for the simple task above:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUWYZ]+");
```

Any of you know any shorthand way of excluding certain letters from a Java regex? Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `&&` operator to create a compound character class using subtraction:

```
String regex = "[A-Z&&[^IVX]]+";
```

Comment: Thank you, this class intersector (?) was a lifesaver in [**R**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)!  Now it's a breeze to take the complement of one class (`[:subset:]`) in another (`[:superset:]`): simply `[[:superset:]&&[^[:subset:]]]`!

Answer (score 26):

You could simply specify character ranges inside your character class:

```
[A-HJ-UWYZ]+
```

Comment: accepted answer didnt work for me (C'), but this does.

Answer (score 7):

Just use a negative lookahead in your pattern.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?![IVX])[A-Z])+$");
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vW2pQ7/7)

Comment: Or you could use this `^(?:(?=[^IVX])[A-Z])+$`

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

'&&' didn't work for me,

used: `(?:(?![IVX])[A-Z])`

Answer (score 1):

Use `[A-Z&&[^IVX]]+` to exclude certain characters from the `A-Z` range - see [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)