# text cleansing and regular expression

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am attempting to clean a string of messy text data with `gsub` using regular expression input. I have the following expression:

```
x <- gsub("[^\\x{00}-\\x{7A}]", "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

This expression excludes everything except members  on hexadecimal list 00 - 7A. (See list below for reference.)

**My question is:** Is there a way to rewrite this expression to still exclude certain members of this list? For example, I want it to exclude hex 5F.  I am new to regular expressions and not sure how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Your curent expression matches all chars other than a range. By excluding a char from the range means you want to match it. Thus, you just want an alternation: `x <- gsub("[^\\x{00}-\\x{7A}]|\\x{5F}", "", x, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Remove 5F from the range:

```
x <- gsub("[^\\x{00}-\\x{5E}\\x{60}-\\x{7A}]", "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Do you know if the approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25609010/3576984) works in R? I couldn't get it going...

Comment: @MichaelChirico: It is possible with stringr methods that use ICU library (the syntax is a bit different from Java though).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x <- as.data.table(x)

x <- x[,lapply(.SD,function(x){gsub("_","",x)})]
```

Comment: Please try to provide context with your answer.  A standalone answer may solve a problem in this specific scenario, but an explanation may solve many future problems.  Try to include what you think is causing the issue and why your answer will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a PCRE regex that matches all non-ASCII chars (BTW, an equivalent PCRE regex is `"[^[:ascii:]]"`).

You ask if you can still match all chars other than ASCII, but match a character from the ASCII range, `5F` (an underscore).

The easiest approach here is to use *alternation*:

```
x <- gsub("[^\\x{00}-\\x{7A}]|\\x{5F}", "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

The `|` means *OR*, so that regex above will match all non-ASCII chars and an underscore. See the [R online demo](http://ideone.com/uXnAPi).

*Is there an alternative?* - Use [*stringr* package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf) [`str_replace_all`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html) and leverage the [**character set unions**](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp#TOC-Set-Expressions-Character-Classes-):

> `[[a-z][A-Z][0-9]]`  Implicit Logical OR or Union of Sets.  The examples match ASCII
>   `[a-zA-Z0-9]]`              letters and digits.  The two forms are equivalent.

The best use case for this construct is combining negated and non-negated character classes:

```
> library(stringr)
> x <- c("_Gołąb", "Василий_Bam-Bam-Bigelow")
> str_replace_all(x, "[^\\x{00}-\\x{7A}]", "") ## No excluded char
[1] "_Golab"           "_Bam-Bam-Bigelow"
> str_replace_all(x, "[[^\\x{00}-\\x{7A}][\\x{5F}]]", "") ## With an excluded char that is also matched
[1] "Golab"           "Bam-Bam-Bigelow"
```