# Wildcard/Regex search for [A-Z without Q] in Microsoft Word

Tags: regex, ms-word

Is there an expression for excluding a single character from a character range in the (arguably somewhat peculiar) Regex syntax of Microsoft Word?

These don't seem to work:

```
[A-Z\Q]
[A-Z|Q]
[A-Z^Q]
[A-Z!Q]
```

This question is not a duplicate question to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608925/java-regex-include-all-letters-of-the-alphabet-except-certain-letters), since the latter is about Java, and since Word has its own Regex implementation. The fact that some answers over there might be applicable for Word doesn't change that.

Comment: Use a `[A-PR-Z]`

Comment: Awesome! I've seen that even things like [AC-Z] work, if for example I want to exclude "B"

Comment: Re the edit, the relevant regex syntax appears to be exactly the same between Java and Word